# Android - Header in ListView disappears?

Tags: android, listview, header, android-fragments

I've been experiencing a very weird bug lately... and simply don't know what to do...

I have a "Tabbed-Fragment-Activity", which means I needed a tabhost on the bottom so I used google's API example, which manages fragments via the TabHost (& Manager)
Almost each tab is actually a ListFragment and to each I add an header at "OnActivityCreated".

Now the weird thing is : When i move to a tab (ListFragment) the first time, I can see the header, but once I move from the tab and afterwards move back to it, the header is GONE !!!

This is the code I'm using :

```
private boolean initialized = false;
private TextView m_Header = null; 


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    String listTitle = "HELLO HUMAN"
    if(m_Header == null && !Helpers.isNullOrBlank(listTitle))
    {
        m_Header = (TextView)inflater.inflate(R.layout.newslist_header, null, false);
        m_Header.setText(listTitle);
    }


    return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    if(!initialized)
    {
        ListView list = getListView();
        if(m_Header != null)
        {
            list.addHeaderView(m_Header);
        }

        this.m_adapter = new SomeAdapter();
        setListAdapter(this.m_adapter);     
        registerForContextMenu(list);
        this.initialized = true;
    }

}
```

I'm using this "initialized" boolean as to not call "setListAdapter"/"addHeader" each time I load the fragment (otherwise you get a nasty exception saying you can't add header after setting the adapter...)

Errr... i'm clueless @ this point...

please help :)

Answer (score 2):

Use the view typing system in `BaseAdapter`. Using `addHeaderView()` wraps your adapter and adds unnecessary complexity that you don't need for a single `View`. The `getItemViewType(int)` method let's you differentiate `View` types based on position within the adapter. In your `getView()` method you can check to see if the position is for the header. For example:

```
public class YourAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
   private static final int HEADER = 0;
   private static final int CELL   = 1;

   @Override public int getItemViewType(int position) {
      if (position == 0) {
         return HEADER;
      }
      return CELL;
   }

   @Override public int getViewTypeCount() {
      return 2;
   }

   @Override
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      if (getItemViewType(position) == HEADER) {
         // do header stuff...
         return yourHeaderView;
      }

      // do non header stuff...
      return yourNonHeaderView;
   }
}
```